# $AB=I_{n \times n}$ and $CA=I_{m \times m}$ prove that $m=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$, $AB=I_{n \times n}$, $CA=I_{m \times m}$, prove that $n=m$.

Is using inverse matrix is a valid solution?

Comment: No, it is not. Argue instead in terms of the rank of $A$.

Comment: The inverse matrix of what?  Note that $A,B,C$ cannot (in general) have inverses since they are not square.  They can, however, have pseudoinverses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $CA = I_{m \times m}$, we may conclude that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent (why?).

Because $AB = I_{n \times n}$, we may conclude that the rows of $A$ (i.e. the columns of $A^T$) are linearly independent.

Since these two events coincide, we must conclude that $A$ is square (why?).

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 equations  and u know that to multiply matrices  **MxN** size the other one must be **NxK** and they give an **MxK** size matrix .Try multiply on  your facts and try to make a contradiction to the Size of the **I** matrix.That is what i would do.I think it will work .And you cant say that the **A** matrix is inversable  in general.

Comment: Omnomnomnom's answer will do it :D